# How to get url of all schools using pagination

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to get links of all schools.  I'm getting links from first page, I want to get links of school from all pages.

```
import requests,re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = requests.get('https://www.maxpreps.com/rankings/football/1/stat/alabama.htm')
soup = BeautifulSoup(url.content,'lxml')
My_table = soup.find('table',{'class':'mx-grid sortable rankings-grid'})
links = My_table.findAll('a')
print(links)
```

Comment: Is this some type of assignment? This exact question was asked 4 hours ago by another post.

Comment: No idea ,can you help me with pagination